# The function called inside the 'map_changed' listener of Google Maps is called multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow, markerclusterer

I am using markerclustererplus with Google Maps. I have multiple markers and I have set it so that only one InfoWindow displays at a time. If the user clicks on a marker, an InfoWindow appears. If the user zooms out and the marker is absorbed into a cluster, the InfoWindow is closed.

I use the 'map_changed' listener to the markers to check if the marker has been "absorbed" into a cluster.  If so, the InfoWindow is closed and I want to call another function one time only.  The problem is that in my current code, the function gets called for multiple markers.

How can I either add the 'map_changed' listener to the currently-selected marker only? If this is not possible, how can I prevent the function being called multiple times? Do I need to temporarily
remove the 'map_changed' listener to non-selected markers?

The function I want to call is named "closeMarker()".  Please see the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cx7thwv/1/).

**JS:**

```
var map;

function loadMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -41.75,
      lng: 172.75
    },
    zoom: 4
  });

  addMarkers();
}
var WeatherStations = [{
    "stn": 719460,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "FORT SIMPSON",
    "FIPS": "CA",
    "Latitude": 61.759998322,
    "Longitude": -121.2369995,
    "Elevation_m": 169,
    "NOAAReadings": 14952
  }, {
    "stn": 935970,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "CAPE CAMPBELL AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -41.71699905,
    "Longitude": 174.26699829,
    "Elevation_m": 32,
    "NOAAReadings": 12174
  },
  {
    "stn": 934360,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "WELLINGTON INTL",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -41.32699966,
    "Longitude": 174.80499268,
    "Elevation_m": 12,
    "NOAAReadings": 9914
  }, {
    "stn": 937090,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "HAAST AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -43.86700058,
    "Longitude": 169,
    "Elevation_m": 5,
    "NOAAReadings": 14371
  },
  {
    "stn": 935270,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "FAREWELL SPIT AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -40.54999924,
    "Longitude": 173,
    "Elevation_m": 3,
    "NOAAReadings": 11575
  }, {
    "stn": 935460,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "NELSON AERODROME AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -41.29999924,
    "Longitude": 173.19999695,
    "Elevation_m": 6,
    "NOAAReadings": 10557
  },
  {
    "stn": 937800,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "CHRISTCHURCH INTL",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -43.48899841,
    "Longitude": 172.53199768,
    "Elevation_m": 38,
    "NOAAReadings": 14933
  }, {
    "stn": 938050,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "PUYSEGUR POINT AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -46.15000153,
    "Longitude": 166.6000061,
    "Elevation_m": 44,
    "NOAAReadings": 10493
  },
  {
    "stn": 939940,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "RAOUL ISLAND AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -29.25,
    "Longitude": -177.9329987,
    "Elevation_m": 50,
    "NOAAReadings": 11001
  }
];

var styles = [
  [{
    url: "https://i.imgur.com/4dzjY47.png",
    height: 47,
    width: 48,
    anchorText: [14, 0],
    textColor: '#fff',
    textSize: 11
  }, {
    url: 'https://i.imgur.com/My5Cgpd.png',
    height: 47,
    width: 48,
    anchorText: [14, 0],
    textColor: '#fff',
    textSize: 11
  }, {
    url: 'https://i.imgur.com/t7SvOax.png',
    height: 47,
    width: 48,
    anchorText: [14, 0],
    textColor: '#fff',
    textSize: 11
  }]
];

var prev_infowindow = false; // to close previously-opened infowindows
var dataSourceType = 0; // 0 = grid; 1 = weatherstation
var gStn;
var gWban;
var gMarkerLat;
var gMarkerLng;
var gMarkerName;
var iw;
var iwClosed = false;
var curMark;
var infowindow;

function addMarkers() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var markers = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < WeatherStations.length; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(WeatherStations[i].Latitude, WeatherStations[i].Longitude)

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      visible: true,
      zIndex: 10,

    });

    var content = "<div id='" + WeatherStations[i].stn + " '> <div class='scrollfix'><b>" + WeatherStations[i].StationName + "</b>";

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        curMark = this;
        // Close already-opened InfoWindow
        if (prev_infowindow) {
          prev_infowindow.close();
        }

        prev_infowindow = infowindow;

        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.setOptions({
          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -42)
        })
        infowindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition())
        infowindow.open(map, /* marker */ );
      };
    })(marker, content, infowindow));


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {

      var clusters = markerClusterer.getClusters(); // use the get clusters method which returns an array of objects

      for (let i = 0, l = clusters.length; i < l; i++) {
        const markers = clusters[i].getMarkers();
        for (const m of markers) {
          if (m === curMark && markers.length > 1) {


            try {
              if (infowindow !== null) {

                infowindow.close();
                infowindow = null;
              }
              if (prev_infowindow) {
                prev_infowindow.close();
              }
                         closeMarker();
            } catch (ee) {}
          }
        }
      }
    });

    markers.push(marker);
  }

  var zoom = null;
  var size = null;
  var style = 0;

  markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    maxZoom: zoom,
    gridSize: size,
    styles: styles[style]
  });
}

function clearClusters() {
  markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
}

function closeMarker()
{
    console.log('x');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Google Maps Marker Example</title>
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" async defer></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="mark.js"></script>
      <script>
      
        
      </script>
      <style>
        #map {
          width: 500px;
          height: 500px;
          border: thin solid black;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadMap();">
      <h1>Google Maps Marker Example</h1>
      <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to address the issue would be to set the variable `curMark` to `null` when you close it's `InfoWindow` and move the call to `closeMark` to the code that closes the `InfoWindow` and sets the `curMark` variable to `null`.

Also, not sure why you are setting `infowindow` to `null` there, but if you do that, it will only call `closeMarker` one time.

Updated `map_changed` listener:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
   var clusters = markerClusterer.getClusters(); // use the get clusters method which returns an array of objects
   for (let i = 0, l = clusters.length; i < l; i++) {
     const markers = clusters[i].getMarkers();
     for (const m of markers) {
       if (m === curMark && markers.length > 1) {
         try {
           if (infowindow !== null) {
             infowindow.close();
             closeMarker();
             curMark=null;
           }
           if (prev_infowindow) {
             prev_infowindow.close();
           }
         } catch (ee) {}
      }
     }
   }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ktwcbuzj/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function loadMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -41.75,
      lng: 172.75
    },
    zoom: 4
  });

  addMarkers();
}
var WeatherStations = [{
    "stn": 719460,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "FORT SIMPSON",
    "FIPS": "CA",
    "Latitude": 61.759998322,
    "Longitude": -121.2369995,
    "Elevation_m": 169,
    "NOAAReadings": 14952
  }, {
    "stn": 935970,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "CAPE CAMPBELL AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -41.71699905,
    "Longitude": 174.26699829,
    "Elevation_m": 32,
    "NOAAReadings": 12174
  },
  {
    "stn": 934360,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "WELLINGTON INTL",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -41.32699966,
    "Longitude": 174.80499268,
    "Elevation_m": 12,
    "NOAAReadings": 9914
  }, {
    "stn": 937090,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "HAAST AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -43.86700058,
    "Longitude": 169,
    "Elevation_m": 5,
    "NOAAReadings": 14371
  },
  {
    "stn": 935270,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "FAREWELL SPIT AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -40.54999924,
    "Longitude": 173,
    "Elevation_m": 3,
    "NOAAReadings": 11575
  }, {
    "stn": 935460,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "NELSON AERODROME AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -41.29999924,
    "Longitude": 173.19999695,
    "Elevation_m": 6,
    "NOAAReadings": 10557
  },
  {
    "stn": 937800,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "CHRISTCHURCH INTL",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -43.48899841,
    "Longitude": 172.53199768,
    "Elevation_m": 38,
    "NOAAReadings": 14933
  }, {
    "stn": 938050,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "PUYSEGUR POINT AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -46.15000153,
    "Longitude": 166.6000061,
    "Elevation_m": 44,
    "NOAAReadings": 10493
  },
  {
    "stn": 939940,
    "wban": 99999,
    "StationName": "RAOUL ISLAND AWS",
    "FIPS": "NZ",
    "Latitude": -29.25,
    "Longitude": -177.9329987,
    "Elevation_m": 50,
    "NOAAReadings": 11001
  }
];

var styles = [
  [{
    url: "https://i.imgur.com/4dzjY47.png",
    height: 47,
    width: 48,
    anchorText: [14, 0],
    textColor: '#fff',
    textSize: 11
  }, {
    url: 'https://i.imgur.com/My5Cgpd.png',
    height: 47,
    width: 48,
    anchorText: [14, 0],
    textColor: '#fff',
    textSize: 11
  }, {
    url: 'https://i.imgur.com/t7SvOax.png',
    height: 47,
    width: 48,
    anchorText: [14, 0],
    textColor: '#fff',
    textSize: 11
  }]
];

var prev_infowindow = false; // to close previously-opened infowindows
var dataSourceType = 0; // 0 = grid; 1 = weatherstation
var gStn;
var gWban;
var gMarkerLat;
var gMarkerLng;
var gMarkerName;
var iw;
var iwClosed = false;
var curMark;
var infowindow;

function addMarkers() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var markers = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < WeatherStations.length; i++) {
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(WeatherStations[i].Latitude, WeatherStations[i].Longitude)

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map,
      visible: true,
      zIndex: 10,

    });

    var content = "<div id='" + WeatherStations[i].stn + " '> <div class='scrollfix'><b>" + WeatherStations[i].StationName + "</b>";

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, content, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        curMark = this;
        // Close already-opened InfoWindow
        if (prev_infowindow) {
          prev_infowindow.close();
        }

        prev_infowindow = infowindow;

        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.setOptions({
          pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -42)
        })
        infowindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition())
        infowindow.open(map);
      };
    })(marker, content, infowindow));


    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'map_changed', function() {
      var clusters = markerClusterer.getClusters(); // use the get clusters method which returns an array of objects
      for (let i = 0, l = clusters.length; i < l; i++) {
        const markers = clusters[i].getMarkers();
        for (const m of markers) {
          if (m === curMark && markers.length > 1) {
            try {
              if (infowindow !== null) {

                infowindow.close();
                closeMarker();
                curMark=null;
              }
              if (prev_infowindow) {
                prev_infowindow.close();
              }
            } catch (ee) {}
          }
        }
      }
    });

    markers.push(marker);
  }

  var zoom = null;
  var size = null;
  var style = 0;

  markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    maxZoom: zoom,
    gridSize: size,
    styles: styles[style]
  });
}

function clearClusters() {
  markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
}

function closeMarker() {
  console.log('x');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Google Maps Marker Example</title>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" async defer></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@googlemaps/markerclustererplus/dist/index.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #map {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      border: thin solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body onload="loadMap();">
  <h1>Google Maps Marker Example</h1>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```